# Printing Latex generated pdf to a roll of labels

Tags: formatting, labels, printing

Wondering if anyone ever worked with (or tried to) printing to a ROLL of labels (ie. NOT discrete pieces of paper like A4).

Is it just a matter of setting the length of the page really long? Or perhaps i'm not thinking straight?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I like the question.  But, I think the answer is not really in the realm of TeX or LaTeX, having more to do with OS, drivers etc.  So listing your OS and make and model of label printer, etc. might help.  Most likely each label will be a page and the `geometry` package can handle the dimensional challenge. Of course drivers can sometimes be a problem. Did you try anything to solve this problem on your own?  If yes, then post your attempted code in full.

Comment: I think the exact dimensions of each label would also be needed information.

Comment: Basically it should be the `geometry` settings only, but a TeX page can't be arbitrarily large of course

Comment: Thanks A Feldman and Christian Hupfer. That's great i'll play around with those settings.  I basically didn't know where to begin. I'm using a script to write out a .tex file, compiling and printing it, so for each run should be able to alter the geometry or pages according to the number of labels needed (between 1 to a few hundred). thanks i should have enough to get started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution, if i understand you need to set `paperheight=\maxdimen` option of geometry

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=.5cm, 
            paperwidth=6cm, 
            paperheight=\maxdimen]{geometry}
\newcommand*{\labelwd}{5cm}
\newcommand*{\labelht}{5cm}

\newcounter{labelno}% just for the example
\begin{document}
\loop
\par\noindent
\fbox{% just for the example
\parbox[t][\labelht][t]{\labelwd}{%
% begin label contents 
\stepcounter{labelno}
\centering
\huge bla bla

\thelabelno
% end  label contents 
}}
\ifdim\dimexpr\pagegoal-\pagetotal-\baselineskip\relax>\labelht
\repeat


\end{document}
```

Comment: please ask if you see any problem.

Comment: thanks again i'll also post the modified script if i get it to work, hopefully in the next few days.

Comment: This is really cool.  109 labels--on one page.